# Activating virtual environment doesn't import environment variables

Tags: linux, bash, python, virtualenv

I am trying to write a bash script which runs a couple of python management commands overnight.

I read from other posts that you need to `source` the virtualenv to be able to import the environment variables, however even after having added the command it still does not work:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/DDiran/.virtualenvs/envname/bin/activate && cd 
/home/DDiran/projectdir/ && python manage.py randomize_product_order && 
python manage.py update_product_prices
```

The var in question is `$PRODUCTION_ENV` and it results empty (raising a python `KeyError: None`)

What am I doing wrong, and why?

**EDIT**

As requested by @Romeo Ninov, contents of `bin/activate`: https://pastebin.com/7yAbZxrX

The environment variables are set in `bin/postactivate` which is set to run immediately after `bin/activate` I think? That's how it usually works when activating the virtualenv.

Comment: What is the content of `/home/DDiran/.virtualenvs/envname/bin/activate`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov edited post with source code of activate

Comment: So when you run source /home/DDiran/.virtualenvs/envname/bin/activate on it's own, can you echo $PRODUCTION_ENV and get the required output?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Nope it doesn't work...

Comment: There is no $PRODUCTION_ENV variables referenced in bin/activate?

Comment: @RamanSailopal Yes, this is because the virtualenv docs state that environment variables must be exported in `bin/postactivate`

Answer (score 0):

After conducting further research I found two different solutions. I'll post it here for anyone who has a similar issue in future:

### **Solution #1**

As per [this post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965475/cannot-activate-virtual-environment-with-a-shell-script), the actual script itself needs to be sourced, so instead of:

`bash myscript.sh`

It needs to be:

`source myscript.sh`

Full explanation of why this needs to happen is in the link above.

### **Solution #2**

Is a lot easier. Instead of activating the virtual environment and running:

`python manage.py my_command`

You simply run:

`/path/to/virtual/env/bin/python manage.py my_command`

This way you don't have to worry about activating the virtual environment at all and the environment variables you set in your virtualenv will be there.